# Make an Interface method return type the implemented class

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'd like to make an interface that forces implementing classes to (statically, if possible) implement a method returning an instance of themselves.

If I have

```
interface MyInterface {
  foo: string;
  getNewInstance(): MyInterface;
}
```

I can implement it like that

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;

  getNewInstance(): MyInterface {
    return {foo: "test"};
  }
}
```

I can't find a way to force the implementation to return an instance of the implementation. And even less how to make it static.

For context, I'm using MyInterface as a generic, `AbstractClass<T extends MyInterface>`, and I want my `MyClass<MyImplementation>` to be able to generate a new instance of `MyImplementation`.

I know there are other ways to do it, most likely better, and I'll use another way, like forcing my class using the generic to implement it, like below. But I wanted to know if my first idea was even possible, as it would allow to put the class declaration and the instance generation in the same place.

```
AbstractClass<T extends MyInterface> {
  abstract getNewInstance(): T;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: mind you this is Java-ish syntax, but the concepts I believe transfer: `interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface>`, `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<MyImplementation>`, and then `getNewInstance(): T`.

Comment: The problem with that is that I can do `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<AnotherImplementation>`, and my class using the generic doesn't know which type the method returns

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBBMbN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, that's the same answer as Rogue and Unreal below, after fiddling with it, it kind of does if the class using the generic uses `<T extends MyInterface<T>>`. But the method is not static, so it wouldn't really work for what I want to do.

Comment: It's the same answer "after fiddling with it"?  I'm confused.

Comment: (see prev comment).  Note even without the "return the implemented class" part, there's no way to have an interface describe static things, or constrain the static side of a class with an implements clause (see [ms/TS#33892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892)). These are essentially separate concerns; which one is the main question here: "how do I constrain the static side of a class" or "how do I get the return type to be the same as the current class instance"?

Comment: @jcalz after trying more stuff in my code. At first, I didn't use `MyAbstractClass<T extends MyInterface<T>>` so I was able to do `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<AnotherImplementation>`. I was interested in both concerns, since considering my use case, one is useless without the other.

Comment: You may be interested in both but they are different issues.  Please choose one to be primary here.  You can always open multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

should omit `getNewInstance` when return:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    getNewInstance(): Omit<T, 'getNewInstance'>;
}

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<MyImplementation> {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
    
    // will see the error: Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }'
    getNewInstance() {
        return {foo: "test"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work,, it doesn't force the implementing class to return an instance of itself.

Comment: it doesn't prevent doing `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<AnotherImplementation>`, and my class using the generic doesn't know which type the method returns.

Comment: Actually, if my generic class uses `<T extends MyInterface<T>>` it forces the the right implementation. But it's quite weird to use, and it's not static anyway.